# Why don't all the elements of my form align right?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I don't understand why all of the elements of my form aren't following the `align="right"` tag. Ideally, I want everything to be centered, but I noticed that the section to type the question, add money, and add tags stay to the left while the sections to add a file and the submit button are the only elements that follow the alignment rule in the `<form>` tag. Why is this? How can I align everything *together*?

**HTML**

```
    <div class="container">
        <!--Sections: Question, Add money, Add file, Submit-->
        <form role="form" align="right">

        <!-- Section to type question-->
            <div class="form-group" id="AddQuestion">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Search"></textarea>
            </div>

        <!--Section to add money---->
            <div class="input-group" id="AddMoney">
              <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
              <input id="EnterMoney" type="text" class="form-control" onkeypress='validate(event)'>
            </div>

        <!--Section to add tags-->
            <div class="input-group" id="AddTag">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Tags" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            </div>

        <!--Section to add file-->
            <div id="AddFile">
                <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('uploadFile').click(); return false;" />Add File</a>
                <input type="file" id="uploadFile" style="visibility: hidden;" />
            </div>

            <div id="imagePreview"></div>

        <!--Section for the Submit button-->
            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
form {

}
.container {
    max-width:500px;
}
#imagePreview {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;   
    display: inline-block;
}
#AddMoney {
    max-width:200px;
}
#AddFile {
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
}
#AddTag {
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting this image? http://gyazo.com/9dd10df99ab96937c710bd80415cea82

Answer (score 0):

Its because other CSS class applied on your controls. E.g your `div` and `textarea` have CSS class `form-group` and `form-control` respectively. Check your CSS and you will be able to see which CSS class is causing this.

You can open developer tool of browser using F12 button and it will show you respective HTML and CSS when you inspect the element.

Hope this will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: I've added the CSS to my question. Note that my `form` in the CSS code is blank (it was always blank), yet the form still does not follow the alignment - why is this?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? It seems that some or either way your form controls have their CSS which align them according to that. Did you try developer tool to inspect the CSS applied on your control?

Answer (score 0):

The align property for HTML went out of date with the release of HTML5 and CSS3. A good work around is using CSS properties to align elements using the margin-left or margin-right property.

```
#example {

margin-left: 1px; /*play around with these values*/
margin-right 1px; /*play around with these values*/
}
```

play around with these values and they should get you what you need. You can also use percentage values for margin left and right if you want.

Comment: Did they replace `align` with something else or are we just expected to use CSS? Also, why does it still have an effect on my end result if it went out of date?

Comment: I think the assumption is that your supposed to use CSS. 

Honestly I don't know why it has an effect, maybe an error? However I know 100% that it went out of date. Look up the align attribute on http://www.w3schools.com/, you will see that the attribute went out of date with HTML5.

Hope this helps! :) direct link right here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_div_align.asp

Comment: Lol I love how point blank they make it sound on their website. Thanks for the assist @Chris

Comment: @whatin1992 - The attribute on the form element only has a effect in Chrome, not IE or Firefox. Chrome does so because of a user-agent stylesheet rule, and since no spec enforces browser stylesheet rules it cannot be said to be a bug. HTML5 *suggests* that the attribute should only have an effect when on `<div>` elements and that's what the other browsers do.